# Calendar in Java 1.6 - strange result

Tags: java, date, calendar

I use this code:

```
        java.util.GregorianCalendar cal1 = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
        cal1.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 22);
        cal1.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        cal1.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        System.out.println(">>> date=" + cal1.getTime());
```

When I run it at 15:58 it prints:

> > > date=Thu Jun 13 10:20:00 CEST 2013

When I run it at 07:00 it prints:

> > > date=Wed Jun 12 22:20:00 CEST 2013

I need it always to print the last result. I am probably doing something incorrectly, but I am wondering the reason for these two results depending on time of day I run it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're setting [`HOUR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) when you should be setting [`HOUR_OF_DAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY).

`HOUR` modifies the value as seen in "10 AM" or "10 PM". Both 10s are the same value. The "correct" range of this field is 0-11.

`HOUR_OF_DAY` is the hour as specified in the 24 hour clock.